# Powershell to scan 2 csv files in folder and rename one of them

Tags: csv, powershell

im having trouble writing a piece of code that will scan a folder for two csv files. File1 will have variable name (its different in each folder), while File2 is always static. What i want is to take the name of File1.csv and then make a subfolder and place File2.csv there, and rename File2.csv to match File1.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes it's possible. How will you know which file is File1 if the name can be anything? Are there *only* two CSV files?

Comment: Yes, there are only two files in folder, i was thinking to scan all files with .csv extension, and then do a if $file is not File2.csv, then take the name and store it as, lets say $filenamefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work assuming there's only two CSV files in the folder and File2.csv always has the same name.

```
$folderPath = 'C:\Folder'
Add-Content -Path "$folderPath\File1.csv" -Value ''
Add-Content -Path "$folderPath\File2.csv" -Value ''

$file1 = (Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter '*.csv').where({ $_.Name -ne 'File2.csv' })

$newFolderPath = "$folderPath\$($file1.Name)"

$null = mkdir $newFolderPath
Move-Item -Path "$folderPath\File2.csv" -Destination "$newFolderPath\$($file1.Name)"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch man. Really appreciate your help. Unfortunately, it gives me following error 

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'where'.
At line:14 char:1
+ $file1 = (Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter '*.csv').where({ $_.Name -ne $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Ok, i found what was the problem, i was using Powershell V3, i just updated to V4 and works like a charm ! Thank you buddy !